# how to center the table on the page without following the margin

Tags: tables, center

How to center the table in the page??

```
\begin{table}[H]
  \caption{Variabili selezionate per l'indice tecnico di telelavoro }
  \label{tbl:tabVar1}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.63]{img/tab1.png}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: why include the table as an image? It looks like you could easily set it as a latex table within the margins. but if you have the image you can replace scale= by width=\textwidth so it fits.

Comment: Add `\centering` before the image and consider some like `width=.5\linewidth` to scale the image to the 50% of the width of the text , instead of the `scale`  option that  depend on the image original size,  not of the available text area.

Comment: what do the article book and memoir class options do?? `book` class doesn't have any of those options

Answer (score 2):

As David pointed out in a comment, this table can be created in latex, so you do not have to include it as an image (this causes e.g. different fonts and font sizes as you can see in your screenshot). I think I used a common style to display the table, but of coure you can adapt it to make it look like in your screenshot.

Some notes about the code I used:

- `\centering` is better than `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` because it does not add whitespace.
- `\clap` tells the compiler, that its argument has a width of 0 and centers it (compare `\llap`,`\rlap`).
- The empty `\mbox` is needed before `\clap` in this case to have some content inside the table (the compiler can't "look" into the argument of an `\mbox`).
- `>{\bfseries}l` produces a left aligned column which is printed bold.

```
\begin{document}
   
   \lipsum[1]
   
   \begin{table}[!h]
      \centering
      \mbox{}\clap{
         \begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries }l l l l }
            \toprule
            variabile                                        & \bfseries scala     & \bfseries unità & \bfseries fonte \\ \midrule
            Vendere o influenzare gli altri                  & Importanza (0--100) & Cifra CP 5      & lcp             \\
            Formazione e insegnamento degli altri            & Importanza (0--100) & Cifra CP 5      & lcp             \\
            Assistere e prendersi cura degli altri           & Importanza (0--100) & Cifra CP 5      & lcp             \\
            Esibirsi o lavorare direttamente con il pubblico & Importanza (0--100) & Cifra CP 5      & lcp             \\ \bottomrule
         \end{tabular}
      }
      \label{tab:variabili}
      \caption{Variabili selezionate per l'indice di interazione sociale.}
   \end{table}
   
   \lipsum[1]
   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may liked the following table design:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,  tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \small
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries\raggedright}X llc @{}}
        \toprule
variabile                               & \bfseries{scala}      & \bfseries {unità}& \bfseries{ fonte} \\
        \midrule
Vendere o influenzare gli altri         & Importanza (0--100) & Cifra CP 5      & lcp             \\
Formazione e insegnamento degli altri   & Importanza (0--100) & Cifra CP 5      & lcp             \\
Assistere e prendersi cura degli altri  & Importanza (0--100) & Cifra CP 5      & lcp             \\
Esibirsi o lavorare direttamente 
con il pubblico                         & Importanza (0--100) & Cifra CP 5      & lcp             \\
     \bottomrule
     \end{tabularx}
\caption{Variabili selezionate per l'indice di interazione sociale.}
\label{tab:variabili}
   \end{table}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```